# Next.js application working in development but failing during building and deployment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

My Next.js app compiles and runs locally during development (*using npm run dev*) but when I attempt to build the project it fails (*using npm run build*). I have read online that this may be due to unhandled promises.

I make fetch requests in my application so I have a suspicion that it may be due to the longer response times with a fully built model versus the faster development model that is causing this issue.

**Error message:**

```
    Error: Export encountered errors
    at _default (/Users/danbarclay/Documents/GitHub/NeoLinkID/node_modules/next/dist/export/index.js:19:1086)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async build (/Users/danbarclay/Documents/GitHub/NeoLinkID/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:36:218)
Automatically optimizing pages .npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! learn-starter@0.1.0 build: `next build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the learn-starter@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/danbarclay/.npm/_logs/2020-06-30T15_50_48_033Z-debug.log
Dans-MBP:neolinkid danbarclay$ npm run build
```

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "learn-starter",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "formik": "^2.1.4",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "next": "9.3.5",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.1"
  }
}
```

The full code is hosted at https://www.github.com/dgbarclay/NeoLinkID if this will help with the debugging.

Any help or pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Step 1: cd into you project folder

```
cd projectFolderName
```

Step 2: Cleans the npm cache:

```
npm cache clean
```

Step 3: Remove the node_modules from you project:

```
rm -rf node_modules
```

Step 4: reinstall node_modules

```
npm install
```

Then try to build you project again. Also you might want to remove the `//` comments / commented out code in your project. I have had some issues with commented out code while using nextjs with the typical forward slash comments `//`
Hope this works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I managed to solve this issue by resolving other type errors in my code but it's useful to know about the commented code issue you've had previously. They may help me in future. Cheers.